# NestJs - How Debug jest tests using typescript

Tags: node.js, typescript, jestjs, nestjs

I am trying to debug my jest tests using typescript and Nestjs framework. I tried a lot of commands but none of them seem works. I have also tried this script provided by [NestJs typescript starter](https://github.com/nestjs/typescript-starter) but it doesn't work as well.

Here's the command:

"`test:debug": "node --inspect-brk -r tsconfig-paths/register -r ts-node/register node_modules/.bin/jest --runInBand"`

Every time after I run this command nothing happens, just this message appears in the console:

[image]

All of my tests are working fine without debug mode.

I've found some blog posts/tutorials telling how we can debug jest tests using typescript and ts-jest but none of them worked for me :(

My questions are:

- Do I need to do any extra setting on vscode **launch.json**?
- Why nothing happens when I run the command test:debug? (Nothing happens after ***Debugger listening on ws://127.0.0.1:9229/5f1fa5dd-6450-488b-8e4d-cc9ff3003804*
  For help, see: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/inspector**

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You should enable `auto attach` in your Vscode and then run your script.
You can enable it by running Debug: Toggle Auto Attach command from the Command Palette.

Comment: Thanks. The only thing missing was the auto attach.

Answer (score 1):

There are many ways of debugging jest tests, vscode launch.json is one of them, you can also work with Google Chrome's inspector (chrome://inspect) in the moment you run the web socket it will appear on the devices list and then you add your folder in the chrome inspector. Here you have the [Official Jest Documentation](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/troubleshooting)

Answer (score 1):

With the flag `--inspect-brk` the debugger will immediately break after its started and you have to run continue for the test to start.

Instead you can use the flag `--inspect` which doesn't start the test with a breakpoint.

---

There are different ways of debugging your tests. You can either connect to the debugger with the Chrome Devtools by opening `about:inspect` or for more convenience use built-in debuggers in your IDE like for example Webstorm which has excellent support out of the box. For more information see the [official docs](https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/debugging-getting-started/).